# iOS -post data to java jersery jax-rs web service

Tags: ios, post, jersey

hi im implementing a iOS app which post data to RESTFul web-service implemented in java jersey.

iOS code:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chris", @"name", @"99", @"age", nil];

    NSData * JsonData =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString * jsonString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/testwebservice/submit"]]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                       queue: queue
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (error || !data) {
                                   // Handle the error

                                   NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                               } else {
                                   // Handle the success

                                   NSLog(@"Server Response :%@",response);
                               }
                           }
     ];
```

Java Jersey code:

```
@POST
    @Path("submit")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void postMultivaluedName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> aFormParams) {
        System.out.println("postMultivaluedName");

        System.out.println("Name is " + aFormParams.get("name"));
        System.out.println("Age is " + aFormParams.get("age"));
    }
```

The problem i'm facing is that the value of name and age received on web service is null.

however, if i modify iOS to use this code, it works:

```
NSString *postString = @"name=chris&age=99";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

So how can i modify my java Jersey to accept NSData using NSDictionary?

While debugging, i also notice that jsonString is actually having `@"{\n "name":"chris" \n "age":"99" \n }`. is it suppose to have \n in the string?

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve it. The reason why the following code works is because i set the http content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
NSString *postString = @"name=chris&age=99";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

instead, set the content-type to `application/json; charset=utf-8`